# Compare lists & get match percentage of each element

Tags: python

I have two python lists.

```
A= ['today is sunday', 'today is wednesday']
B= ['today is sunday', 'today is 
     Monday'....'today is Saturday']

 For elm in A:
     If elm in B:
        print ("not ok")
      else:
        print ("ok")
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of matches of elements between two python lists.

The required match percentage calculations are depicted in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be :

```
A= ['today is sunday', 'today is wednesday']
B= ['today is sunday', 'today is monday', 'today is Saturday']
match_percent = (len(set(B).intersection(set(A))))/len(B)*100
print(match_percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly the match percentage you want to calculate, so I've took the liberty to calculate is as `match_count / max(list_a_size, list_b_size)`.

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2] 
    return len(lst3)

def maximum(a, b): 
    if a >= b: 
        return a 
    else: 
        return b 

A= ['today is sunday', 'today is wednesday']
B= ['today is sunday', 'today is Monday', 'today is Saturday']

match_percent = intersection(A, B) / maximum(len(A),len(B))

print(match_percent)
```

Output:

```
0.3333333333333333
```